# .hasClass() not a function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following:

```
$('.myEm').closest('.area').hasClass('medium').toggleClass('large-4 large-12');
```

But I keep getting an error saying .hasClass is not a function. What am I missing?

Comment: If `jQuery` doesn't find anything for `.closest()`, then you're actually calling `.hasClass()` on a non-jquery object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't chain other methods after the [`.hasClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) like that.

The [`.hasClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)  returns a boolean based on whether the jQuery selector has a specific class. It seems like you are looking for the [`.has()` method](https://api.jquery.com/has/), which will filter the collection of element(s) based on whether it has a specific descendant element matching the selector:

```
$('.myEm').closest('.area').has('.medium').toggleClass('large-4 large-12');
```

...or you could use the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) as well:

```
$('.myEm').closest('.area:has(.medium)').toggleClass('large-4 large-12');
```

The reason you can chain most of the other jQuery methods is because they return a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). If you check the documentation on any jQuery method or selector, and you can determine the return type (which will indicate whether you can chain additional methods afterwards). As mentioned above, the `.hasClass()` method doesn't return a jQuery object, it returns `true`/`false`, which is why you are seeing the following error stating that it is not a function:

> Uncaught `TypeError: $(...).closest(...).hasClass(...).toggleClass is not a function`

Comment: Thanks. Quick question: "medium" is a class. Don't I need to have a period before it as in .has('.medium')